# Command works in Command Prompt but not in a batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Trying to print out the 8dot3 name of a file, it does works when I paste the line in the Command Prompt but not when I run it from a batch file.

Result when pasted :

```
D:\tmp>cmd /e:on /c for %A in (8088_othello.com) do @echo %~nxsA

8088_O~1.COM
```

Result from batch file :

```
D:\tmp>lfn.bat

D:\tmp>cmd /e:on /c for ~nxsA

~nxsA was unexpected at this time.
```

What else is needed to make it work inside a batch file ?

Comment: My issue was encoding. When I made bat file to be utf-8 things worked. Previously it was on ucs-2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to escape % is batch files

just type 
cmd /e:on /c for %%A in (8088_othello.com) do @echo %%~nxsA

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html - its for both for loops and passing it to other applications as well

Comment: Good solution. Fixed my problem instantly. I always thought .bat= direct cmd script

Comment: I just double the %% as said and it works, thank you